# How can I avoid word repetition in the following paragraph?

Tags: editing

> Eri knelt down slowly and thought about her world. The one with the
>   solid **ground** in which she had stood all her life. Would that surface
>   break apart one day? And when it did, what would happen to her?
>   Perhaps she would end up floating aimlessly in a vast nothingness. Her
>   feet never touching the **ground** again. Her hands never finding anything
>   to hold onto.

I've been trying to edit this for about an hour. It's like a chess dilemma I created myself. I can't replace *ground* with *surface* because I'm already using it in the next sentence. And it seems like *feet never touching the ground* is the most natural way of saying it. I think *feet touching the soil* and *feet touching the land* sound strange.

Does anyone have a simple, effective way to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"touching the **earth**." A native speaker would use that phrasing. "Earth" in this context has the double meaning of literal soil and "the earth," the planet.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is what I was looking for. I think it works perfectly well, since "Earth" and "earthquake" are recurring motifs in the story.

Comment: Exactly; I was thinking the same thing -- she's all shook up because of the earthquake, so "earth" is going to be on her mind.

Answer (score 4):

One simple, effective way to solve it: Stop editing. It's fine.

Comment: OK I'll try. Not sure whether I will succeed, though.

Comment: Agreed. The secound ground is far enough away to not jar, and its use makes it seem almost like a name of a loved one; something they miss, recalling it twice only strengthens that image. I actually really like it.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the *the*.

*That* ground.
*Any ground*.
*That or any other ground*.

That way this is no longer a repetition, but a back-reference.